# How do I form a composite model class in lmfit out of a varying number of GaussianModels?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, lmfit

I want to make a function that makes a CompositeModel class from adding a differing number of GaussianModel classes.

I tried summing the Gausslist which replaces gauss1 to gauss6. I've also tried just using the Gausslist in place of mod but that does not work.

So Originally I have:

```py
gauss1 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars = gauss1.make_params(center=_259V[0][0], amplitude=_259V[1][0])

gauss2 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars.update(gauss2.make_params(center=_259V[0][1], amplitude=_259V[1][1]))


gauss3 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g3_')
pars.update(gauss3.make_params(center=_259V[0][2], amplitude=_259V[1][2]))

gauss4 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g4_')
pars.update(gauss4.make_params(center=_259V[0][3], amplitude=_259V[1][3]))

gauss5 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g5_')
pars.update(gauss5.make_params(center=_259V[0][4], amplitude=_259V[1][4]))

gauss6 = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g6_')
pars.update(gauss6.make_params(center=_259V[0][5], amplitude=_259V[1][5]))


mod = gauss1 + gauss2 + gauss3 + gauss4 + gauss5 + gauss6
```

This will give me a model made up of six Gaussian functions but I want to generalize it for when I have a smaller or larger number of functions. So far I have done the following which allows me to generate list of GaussianModels (Gausslist) whose length depends on the peak_data. So number of peaks corresponds to how many Gaussians I want:

```py
Gausslist = []
Gausslist.append(models.GaussianModel(prefix='g0_'))
pars = Gausslist[0].make_params(center=_259V[0][0],amplitude=peak_data[1][0])

for i in range(1, len(peak_data[1])):
    Gausslist.append(models.GaussianModel(prefix='g{}_'.format(i)))
    pars.update(Gausslist[i].make_params(center=_259V[0][i], amplitude=peak_data[1][i]))
```

#

But I don't know how to tackle:

```py
mod = gauss1 + gauss2 + gauss3 + gauss4 + gauss5 + gauss6
```

I tried summing the Gausslist which replaces gauss1 to gauss6. I've also tried just using the Gausslist in place of mod but that does not work.

I essentially want to add these GaussianModels to form a CompositeModel but I don't know how to add classes or if thats possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
Gausslist = []
model, params = None, None
for i, peak in enumerate(peak_data[1]):
    comp = models.GaussianModel(prefix='g{}_'.format(i))
    pars = comp.make_params(center=center_val, amplitude=peak[0]) #Hm, maybe?
    if model is None:
        model = comp
        params = pars
    else:
        model += comp
        params.update(pars)
```

Now you should be read to use `model` with however many peaks are in your `peak_data[1]` sequence.

FWIW, I would probably recommend storing both `x` and `y` values for your peak data so that you might be able to do something like:

```py
pars = comp.make_params(center=peak[0], amplitude=peak[1], sigma=1)
```

as that will probably give better starting values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in python reduce function:

```
model = reduce(lambda m1,m2: m1+m2, GaussList)
```

Comment: `reduce` is not a built-in function in Python (it was a built-in in Python2).  Anyway, simply adding the Models is not sufficient -- you also need to combine the Parameters.